# An inequality involving $\mathbb{E}[|X|],\,\mathbb{E}[X^2],\,\mathbb{E}[X^4]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

My question is an exercise which appears in a book on probability theory. Thank for helping.

> Let $X$ be a random variable with $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=1$,
>   $0<\mathbb{E}(X^4)<+\infty$. Prove that: $$\mathbb{E}[\left| X \right|]
>  \geqslant \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\mathbb{E}[ X^4 ]} }}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{E}[X^4]^{1/2}\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\mathbb{E}[X^4]^{1/4}\mathbb{E}[X^4]^{1/4}\mathbb{E}[|X|]$$
So, by the [generalized Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_for_probability_measures) ($r=\frac{2}{3}$ since $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+1=\frac{3}{2}$) we have:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^4]^{1/2}\mathbb{E}[|X|]\geq \mathbb{E}[X^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}=1.$$